# Woocommerce Duplicate Categories On Front End

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce

Since updating Woocommerce to the latest version the product categories in the front end of my store are being duplicated.

I believe this must be a conflict with my theme as there was no problem with the previous version of Woocommerce (an early 3.0 release).

I have tried digging (admittedly I am not an experienced coder) but I can't find the source of the code that is resulting in the duplication.

The issue can be seen here: http://aurello.co.uk/product-category/splashbacks/

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: May this come from the overridden woocommerce templates via the theme… you can check that in Woocommerce > status and at the end of the page there is a list of the templates. If any is in red, it needs to be updated.

Comment: it must be edit into code of page , but for temporary use this ,,,...  .products .products.container-fluid .product-category {
 display: none;
}

add this in style.css in your child theme

Comment: @TechnoDeviser thanks, I tried this but the duplicate category is still there. Thinking I might just have to roll back to the previous version of Woo.

Comment: .products .products.container-fluid .product-category { display: none !important; }